# How do I transfer images from a Fedora 20 computer to an iPhone?

Tags: fedora, files, synchronization, iphone

I have a laptop running Fedora20.  I have an iPhone4S.  I have installed the software suggested [here](http://blog.xenodesystems.com/2014/03/how-to-managesync-your-ios-7-device.html) which allows my laptop to read the iPhone.  I connect my phone to the laptop using a USB cable.  I can see a bunch of files, including all the images that are on the iPhone. I can transfer images from the iPhone to the laptop.

**What I want to do is transfer images from the laptop to the iPhone.**

When I copy and paste images I don' get any error message, but the images never appear on the iPhone.

**How can I sync these images to the iPhone?**

I do not have any other OS available.

(Asking here because "AskDifferent", the Apple StackExchange site is hopeless)

Comment: I can email these images to myself but it's the 21st century and that feels suboptimal.

Comment: What is the software you installed? Please [edit] your question and include what you did and what you installed. Also explain exactly how you copy, into which directory and whether the files can be seen on the phone when it's connected to your computer. I understand that iOS cannot see them but are they there on the phone's filesystem?

Comment: Have you tried just installing [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)? That should take care of your transfer and storage problem.

Comment: Upload them to Google Photos

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an App on the iPhone, which runs a little web server where you can upload the images from any browser to your iPhone. Both devices have to be in the same network. I know that VLC for iPhone uses this technique for video files. 
Just try to search the AppStore for `wifi photo transfer` and try a few apps.

Answer (score 0):

On the computer, create a server that serves files, the Current Working Directory being the folder were the file you want to transfer are (the pictures). For the simplest server of all, look into python -m http.server. This will give you a port number.

Create a local network connection between your two devices. Either with infrastructure (router) or without infrastructure (P2P wifi also known as wifi direct). In this process, you will take note of the IP adress of the computer.

Access the files on the computer, from the phone, using an http client with the URL: http://"COMPUTER_IP_ADDRESS":"PORT"/name_of_file.